# No module named 'sparkpost'

Tags: python, sparkpost

I'm trying to install "Sparkpost" package with pip. The installation is finished, im import it and then I get this error: No module named 'sparkpost'

```
from sparkpost import SparkPost
```

My virtual enviroment is working totally fine....

I follow this guide: https://pypi.org/project/sparkpost/

Comment: If you: *pip list* do you see sparkpost?  Also, are you installing it with or without your VENV active?  you should be doing it in the mode you want to use it.  Finally,  is there more than one copy of python installed on your system?   you can have multiples installed and you may be adding the package to the wrong one of them.  Try the pip commands using python module syntax. example: python -m pip list

Comment: thanks for reply :D i ended up using the builtin send_email in django hehe. It saved me a lot of frustration I think